# Load ldap tree only with server info

Tags: php, ldap

I've been checking jxplorer and I just realize that the software loads all the ldap tree with just your server info (IP, port) and I'm wondering how can I do that with php.

Any clue would be much appreciate.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jxplorer most probably does this by requesting the `namingContexts` from the LDAP-server's `RootDSE`. The namingContexts are the root DN's for which the server serves a database, e.g. o=department,ou=company,c=us. Using this information the application can next do a normal LDAP search to fetch an entire ldap tree.

An LDAP server can host more than one LDAP database each served under a different DN, so in the search result the namingContexts attribute may contain more than one value.

To request the RootDSE from an LDAP server just do a search with an empty search base, and the search filter: `(objectClass=*)`. A server may not answer to this kind of requests though: a simple change in the access control lists of the server prevents serving this information.

A basic yet complete example in PHP to request the root DN's of all LDAP databases served:

```
<?php

$ldapconn = ldap_connect('ldaps://example.com');
ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

$result = ldap_read($ldapconn, '', '(objectclass=*)', array('namingContexts'));
$data = ldap_get_entries($ldapconn, $result);  # ldap_read returns max 1 entry

echo "Naming Contexts: <br/>";
$count = $data[0]['namingcontexts']['count'];
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    echo $data[0]['namingcontexts'][$i], "<br/>";
}

ldap_close($ldapconn);

?>
```

More information about the RootDSE:

- https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/RootDSE
- https://ldap.com/dit-and-the-ldap-root-dse
- https://superuser.com/questions/740877

Comment: Awsome!! I'm gonna check out the script and links provided. Many thanks!!